# Why doesn't .not() work in this case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, web

I have been desperately trying to figure out why .not() will not work in this case

link: http://jsfiddle.net/Kr8SA/4/

Thank you for your help.

```js
$('#site').not('#box')
  .fadeIn();
```

```css
#site {
  display: none;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#box {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="site">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It should be the same element. Not a different element. The `$('#site').not('#box')` means, select the element with `id=site` but not `id=box`.

Comment: `$('#site').not('#box')` means: the set of the element with the `site` ID minus the set of the element with the `box` ID. The first set only contains `#site`. You can’t remove `#box` from that set. You probably meant `$("#site *:not(#box)")` or `$("#site > *:not(#box)")`.

Comment: What do you expect `$('#site').not('#box')` to do? IDs are unique in the document and there is no way same item has  two IDs...

Comment: What I'm trying to do is exclude #box from being faded in, using $("#site *:not(#box)") doesn't help either.

Comment: try $('#site div').not('#box').fadeIn();

Comment: `$("#site > *:not(#box)")` works fine for me. You only want to select the one `<div>` without an ID, right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm trying to do but when I use $("#site > *:not(#box)") it just results in both of them not fading in, is that something on my behalf?

Comment: Ok, it's working now, thanks for the help everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.not` function does not search within all the descendants of the given set. It filters the elements from the set. Since `$('#site').length == 1`, it won't work.

Two alternatives would be

- `$('#site *').not('#box')`
- `$('#site').find('*:not(#box)')`

```js
$('#site *').not('#box').fadeIn()
```

```css
/* Hide the elements we'll fade in */
#site *{
  display: none;
}
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
#box {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="site">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div>Something to show</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot. However, the alternatives you have given me just make both of the divs not fade in.

Comment: Ahh, that's because `#site` is still invisible. If you change the CSS to `#site *{
  display: none; }`, it will work. There are different ways you can solve this.

Comment: There you go, that worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`.not()` works as an exclusion filter the current query result, not on children or other descendents. Your query only contains `#site`. So telling jQuery to exclude `#box` using `.not()` will do nothing.

Your query reads like:

- Include `#site`, our query result only contains `#site` now
- Exclude `#box`, our query doesn't contain `#box` so don't do anything
- Our final query result still only contains `#site`